# Find minimum of function on C#

Tags: c#, math

Suppose I have a polynomial that is determined by the array of coefficients. Coefficients are integers from -100 to 100. My task is to find the max point of this function in the range from 0 to 1 programmatically.

How can I do this?

Comment: Implement one of the many computation methods. Some of them try to solve the mathematical problem, others try to find a faster approximate solution. Asking for help on implementing one of them is on-topic for SO. Asking for someone to offer a ready-made solution is not

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/58787/looking-for-numerical-methods-for-finding-local-maxima-and-minima-of-a-function

Comment: Either this is a pure math/tutorial question, in which case it is off-topic, or it is a library request (ie: http://www.mathdotnet.com/), in which case it is off-topic, or it is asking for help with a specific problem implementing a specific solution thereof (in which case the details are missing and this is off-topic).

Comment: @J... So in your opinion programmers must always rely on a library when dealing with math problem ? So **who** coded the library in the first place ?

Comment: @fjardon No, that is not my opinion.  Please read carefully.  I said **if** it was a pure math question then it is *much too broad* and/or requesting a tutorial of some sort, both of which are off-topic for Stack Overflow.  If it is not that type of question (which we don't know because it is vaguely written) then it *may* be seeking a suggestion for a library to solve this problem with, which is also off-topic for Stack Overflow.  I didn't say anything about how the problem *should* be solved.

Answer (score 1):

Extrema occur at the roots of the first derivative. Compute the latter and rewrite it in the Bernstein basis (this takes the resolution of a triangular linear system). Then the convex hull property tells you where roots are possible/impossible just by looking for changes of signs in the coefficients.

Using the De Casteljau algorithm of subdivision, you can implement a dichotomic process for root refinement. Then, computing the sign of the second derivative at the roots will allow you to tell maxima from minima.